# Changed website permalink structure. Old permalinks show as duplicate content in webmasters tools

Tags: seo, redirects, duplicate-content

I have changed the permalink structure for a website containing about 2000 URLs. The old urls are 301 redirected to the new ones.

Google indexed most of them yet they show as duplicate titles in webmasters tools.

The thing is that after I changed the permalink structure I also changed the Title structure. So considering the fact that google sees the NEW title structure for the old urls it clearly shows that they were re-crawled, but instead of de-indexing them, they are shown in webmasters tools with a notice saying they are duplicate pages of the new ones.

Any idea why this happens ?

I would have expected the new permalinks to replace the old ones and for Google to NOT keep the old ones in the index too and consider them duplicates.

Thank you.

Comment: Simple really... you haven't waited long enough. Google's Webmaster tools is often days to weeks and in some cases months if a high volume of URLS, and some things take longer than others. As long as your positive there are no duplicate titles then move on, nothing to worry about. You can find more related questions and answers regarding [duplicate titles reported by Webmaster Tools](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate+titles+Webmaster+tools).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Coincidence or not my organic traffic dropped exactly from the same day as these urls appeared as duplicated in webmasters tools. Is this to be expected? Until google finishes de-indexing I am to be somehow penalized because of duplicated pages ? Thank you